# how i can get the current action of Kendo Ui Grid paging?

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a grid binded to 50 records that my stored procedure has returned, but in total i have almost 300 records in Database.

Now, I want to customize the paging of `Kendo UI Grid` accordingly. because i have implemented paging through Database and now to navigate to next page i have to send call to Database with attribute (either `"NEXT"`, `"PREVIOUS"`, `"FIRST"`, `"LAST"`) and for that I need to know the current action (`"NEXT"`, `"PREVIOUS"`, `"FIRST"`, `"LAST"`) being called from `Kendo Grid`.

Is there any way to find out that?